How to solve Triple fault in my x86_64 OS GDT?
I want to enable GDT in x86_64 OS by init_gdt() function in kernel.c Where, gdt_entry_t is looks
struct gdt_entry_struct
{// 128 Bit
    uint64_t    limit_low   :16;    // limit = 16+4 = 20
    uint64_t    base_low    :16;    // base = 16+8+8 = 32
    uint64_t    base_mid    :8;
    uint64_t    access      :8;     // access = 8
    uint64_t    limit_up    :4;
    uint64_t    flags       :4;     // flags = 4
    uint64_t    base_up     :8;

    uint32_t    base_top;   // Top 32 bits of base (only used in 64-bit GDT entries)
    uint32_t    reserved;   // Reserved field, usually set to 0
} __attribute__((packed));
typedef struct gdt_entry_struct gdt_entry_t;

and set gdt entries by
void gdt_set_gate(int8_t index, uint64_t base, uint32_t limit, uint8_t access, uint8_t flags){
    gdt_entries[index].limit_low = limit & 0xFFFF;   // set lower 16 bit
    gdt_entries[index].limit_up = limit & 0xF0000;   // set upper 4 bit
    
    gdt_entries[index].base_low = base & 0xFFFF;     // set lower 16 bit
    gdt_entries[index].base_mid = (base >> 16) & 0x00FF0000;    // set middle 8 bit
    gdt_entries[index].base_up = (base & 0xFF000000) >> 24;     // set upper 8 bit
     gdt_entries[index].base_top = (base & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000) >> 32; // set top 32 bit

    gdt_entries[index].access = access;      // set 8 bit
    gdt_entries[index].flags = flags;        // set flag =G DB L 0 => 0 00 
}

and initialize gdt by
void init_gdt(){
    gdt_set_gate(0,0,0x00000,0x00,0x0); // null descriptor selector : 0x0

    gdt_set_gate(1,0,0xFFFFF,0x9A,0xCF); // kernel mode code segment, selector : 0x8
    gdt_set_gate(2,0,0xFFFFF,0x92,0xCF); // kernel mode data segment, selector : 0x10


    gdt_set_gate(3,0,0xFFFFF,0xFA,0xA); // user mode code segment, selector : 0x18
    gdt_set_gate(4,0,0xFFFFF,0xF2,0xCF); // user mode data segment

    // Calculate the GDT limit and base address
    uint16_t limit = (uint16_t) (sizeof(gdt_entries) - 1);
    uint64_t base = (uint64_t) &gdt_entries;
    
    setGdt(limit, base);
    reloadSegments();
}

where external assembly function is
section .text

global setGdt

gdtr DW 0 ; For limit storage
     DQ 0 ; For base storage

setGdt:
   MOV   [gdtr], DI
   MOV   [gdtr+2], RSI
   LGDT  [gdtr]
   RET


global reloadSegments
reloadSegments:
   ; Reload CS register:
   PUSH 0x08                 ; Push code segment to stack, 0x08 is a stand-in for your code segment
   LEA RAX, [rel .reload_CS] ; Load address of .reload_CS into RAX
   PUSH RAX                  ; Push this value to the stack
   RETFQ                     ; Perform a far return, RETFQ or LRETQ depending on syntax

.reload_CS:
   ; Reload data segment registers
   MOV   AX, 0x10 ; 0x10 is a stand-in for your data segment
   MOV   DS, AX
   MOV   ES, AX
   MOV   FS, AX
   MOV   GS, AX
   MOV   SS, AX
   RET

This setup is crashing my OS after bootup by showing following qemu log
CPU Reset (CPU 0)
RAX=000000000000004f RBX=0000000000000000 RCX=00000000000000f0 RDX=ffffffff80006980
RSI=ffffffff80006980 RDI=000000000000004f RBP=ffff8000bff48fd0 RSP=ffff8000bff48fb8
R8 =00000000000000cf R9 =0000000000000000 R10=0000000000000000 R11=0000000000000000
R12=0000000000000000 R13=0000000000000000 R14=0000000000000000 R15=0000000000000000
RIP=ffffffff800025ea RFL=00000006 [-----P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0030 0000000000000000 00000000 00009300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0028 0000000000000000 00000000 00209b00 DPL=0 CS64 [-RA]
SS =0030 0000000000000000 00000000 00009300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0030 0000000000000000 00000000 00009300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0030 0000000000000000 00000000 00009300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0030 0000000000000000 00000000 00009300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 0000000000000000 00000000 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 0000000000000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS64-busy
GDT=     ffff800000015c80 00000037
IDT=     0000000000000000 00000000
CR0=80010011 CR2=ffffffff800025e0 CR3=00000000bff38000 CR4=00000020
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=0000000000000078 CCD=00000000000000f0 CCO=LOGICL
EFER=0000000000000d00
FCW=037f FSW=0000 [ST=0] FTW=00 MXCSR=00001f80
FPR0=0000000000000000 0000 FPR1=0000000000000000 0000
FPR2=0000000000000000 0000 FPR3=0000000000000000 0000
FPR4=0000000000000000 0000 FPR5=0000000000000000 0000
FPR6=0000000000000000 0000 FPR7=0000000000000000 0000
XMM00=0000000000000000 0000000000000000 XMM01=0000000000000000 0000000000000000
XMM02=0000000000000000 0000000000000000 XMM03=0000000000000000 0000000000000000
XMM04=0000000000000000 0000000000000000 XMM05=0000000000000000 0000000000000000
XMM06=0000000000000000 0000000000000000 XMM07=0000000000000000 0000000000000000
XMM08=0000000000000000 0000000000000000 XMM09=0000000000000000 0000000000000000
XMM10=0000000000000000 0000000000000000 XMM11=0000000000000000 0000000000000000
XMM12=0000000000000000 0000000000000000 XMM13=0000000000000000 0000000000000000
XMM14=0000000000000000 0000000000000000 XMM15=0000000000000000 0000000000000000
    12: v=03 e=0000 i=1 cpl=0 IP=0008:00000000000efb0a pc=00000000000efb0a SP=0010:0000000000000fc8 env->regs[R_EAX]=00000000000f6106
EAX=000f6106 EBX=000f3e0a ECX=00000000 EDX=00000cf9
ESI=00000000 EDI=00100000 EBP=00000000 ESP=00000fc8
EIP=000efb0a EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f6180 00000037
IDT=     000f61be 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=000f61c8 CCD=00009e34 CCO=SUBL
EFER=0000000000000000
check_exception old: 0xffffffff new 0xd
    13: v=0d e=001a i=0 cpl=0 IP=0008:00000000000efb0a pc=00000000000efb0a SP=0010:0000000000000fc8 env->regs[R_EAX]=00000000000f6106
EAX=000f6106 EBX=000f3e0a ECX=00000000 EDX=00000cf9
ESI=00000000 EDI=00100000 EBP=00000000 ESP=00000fc8
EIP=000efb0a EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f6180 00000037
IDT=     000f61be 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=000f61c8 CCD=00009e34 CCO=SUBL
EFER=0000000000000000
check_exception old: 0xd new 0xd
    14: v=08 e=0000 i=0 cpl=0 IP=0008:00000000000efb0a pc=00000000000efb0a SP=0010:0000000000000fc8 env->regs[R_EAX]=00000000000f6106
EAX=000f6106 EBX=000f3e0a ECX=00000000 EDX=00000cf9
ESI=00000000 EDI=00100000 EBP=00000000 ESP=00000fc8
EIP=000efb0a EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f6180 00000037
IDT=     000f61be 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=000f61c8 CCD=00009e34 CCO=SUBL
EFER=0000000000000000
check_exception old: 0x8 new 0xd

The es,cs,ds, fs and gs segment registers values are look like okay for me.
Then what is the reason for not loading gdt and showing Triple Fault?
Is it the entries values are wrong?
I need an expert help to find the root cause of the Triple Fault.

CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA] This says you loaded a 32-bit code segment (CS32). It should be CS64 if you want 64-bit mode. I think you up want to change gdt_set_gate(1,0,0xFFFFF,0x9A,0xCF); to gdt_set_gate(1,0,0xFFFFF,0x9A,0xAF);

Note: v=03 suggests you did (or the processor) executed an int3 (v=03) instruction. v=0d (GPF) with e=001a(selector error code) suggests an IDT related error with entry 3 in the IDT. This would have likely occurred because the IDT itself had a zero limit (see: IDT=000f61be 00000000). What I don't know is if the IDT limit is 0 as a result of inadvertently running 64-bit code in 32-bit compatibility mode or if there are other issues in code not being shown. At least fixing the CS to be 64-bit is a starting point.

@MichaelPetch thankyou for your comment...I made gdt_set_gate(1,0,0xFFFFF,0x9A,0xA) along with following changes. uint32_t limit = (uint32_t) (5*sizeof(gdt_entry_t) - 1);` but still have issue

You know, I didn't pay close enough attention and it just occurred to me your gdt_entry_t structure is 16 bytes in size. In long mode GDT entries are 8 bytes in size EXCEPT for system segment descriptors that take up 16 bytes (or 2 8 bytes entries in the GDT): https://wiki.osdev.org/Global_Descriptor_Table#Long_Mode_System_Segment_Descriptor . All of your entries are 16 bytes which is probably causing problems. I don't know how you defined the gdt_entries so maybe you are doing something strange there.

Do you have your project's code in Github or some other service where it can be looked at in its entirety?

Two types of system segment descriptors are LDT and TSS. You have neither of those kinds of descriptors so your GDT should have 5 entries of 8 bytes each, and that is a GDT size of 5*8-1=39 = 0x27.

I have changed into 8 byte . But still no change .My whole code is in https://github.com/baponkar/KeblaOS/tree/main/source-code/x86_64-v1.0

I don't need null descriptor? If we use 1 null descriptor, two kernel code and data segment descriptor and two other user code and data .

Always need a null descriptor as the first 8 byte entry in the GDT.

Okay I cloned your repo and ran the code, I did get a page fault exception. I discovered that in your gdt.s you placed the gdtr in the .text section. .text is set as read/execute. When Limine loads your kernel it sets page permissions. You can't write to a read only page so an attempt to update gdtr fails. You need to put the gdtr in the .data section that is read/write. I made that change and your kernel didn't crash and displayed 8 on the screen (the sizeof test). I looked at the segment registers and they look fine now.

@MichaelPetch Thankyou so much ... You rescue me.

If you want to get your interrupts installed there are some bugs. In idt.h extern void idt_flush(uint32_t); needs to be extern void idt_flush(uint64_t); In idt.s idt_flush is a problem. In 64-bit calling convention the first parameter is not passed on the stack. It is in RDI. You also have to use ret not iret. Change idt_flush to lidt [rdi] sti ret . In idt.c idt_entries[index].offset_2 = (offset >> 32) & 0xFFFFFFFF; needs to be idt_entries[index].offset_3 = (offset >> 32) & 0xFFFFFFFF;
